# How to set Label to iText List

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to achieve the following structure:

```
Label: - Value 1
       - Value 2    
       - Value 3
```

Here is my code:

```
document.add(new Chunk("Label: ", BOLD));
List list = new List(List.UNORDERED);           
list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 1")));
list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 2")));
list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 3")));
document.add(list);
```

But it is generating:

```
Label:
- Value 1
- Value 2
- Value 3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List` functionality doesn't support what you're trying to achieve, so you need to use a workaround using `PdfPTable`. If created the [ListWithLabel](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/ListWithLabel) example that shows the desired result:

```
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setTotalWidth(200);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{ 1, 10 });
    table.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    PdfPCell cell;
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    cell.addElement(new Paragraph("Label"));
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    List list = new List(List.UNORDERED);
    list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 1")));
    list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 2")));
    list.add(new ListItem(new Chunk("Value 3")));
    cell.addElement(list);
    table.addCell(cell);
```